# Recalculating a function after update with VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I won't even pretend I know what I am doing but I am going to ask as this is one of the most frustrating features of VueJS, well, at least for me.

So this is the situation. I have a number of sections creating their own totals and a final total made up of those calculated totals.

I'll give you the basics:

- Parking
- Transport
- Mileage*
- Subsistence

Each of the sections above creates a total from a number of lines of items which works fine at the moment. I'll get to mileage in a minute.

Each of these totals is then calculated into a grand total and also displayed.

At the moment, I am doing something like this:

```
    computed: {
        totalAmount: function() {
            return this.calculateAmount(this.total);
        },

        transportAmount: function () {
            if(this.isLoading === true) return 0;
            return this.total.find(total => total.name == "transport").amount = (this.isLoading === false) ? this.calculateAmount(this.transport) : 0;
        },
        mileageAmount: function () {
            if(this.isLoading === true) return 0;
            return this.total.find(total => total.name == "mileage").amount = (this.isLoading === false) ? this.calculateAmount(this.mileage) : 0;
        },
        parkingAmount: function () {
            if(this.isLoading === true) return 0;
            return this.total.find(total => total.name == "parking").amount = (this.isLoading === false) ? this.calculateAmount(this.parking) : 0;
        },
        subsistenceAmount: function () {
            if(this.isLoading === true) return 0;
            return this.total.find(total => total.name == "subsistence").amount = (this.isLoading === false) ? this.calculateAmount(this.subsistence) : 0;
        }

    },
```

I am sure this is not the most efficient and almost certainly the wrong way to approach this (please correct me, I am self taught).

So my problem is with mileage.

I currently run a calculation for the total of each line based on a cost per mile AT INITIAL RUNTIME (i.e. when it first loads).

```
        calculateMileage(ppm) {
            this.mileage.forEach(e => {
                e.amount = e.mileage * ppm;
            });
        },
```

Nothing too complex but it works.

Here is my problem. The amount for mileage is only created here. I am attempting to update the amount to then automatically update all the rest of the totals.

So I have the following setup:

- Main component displaying all items
- Sub components for adding or updating (pop up boxes)

So adding and updating works great for all other sections as they have a dedicated amount column stored in the database but the mileage one is calculated based on a pence per mile cost and dynamically displayed.

What should I use/try to calculate this figure on adding and updating. I tried using calculated methods but it appears you can't calculate from another calculated method.

Any ideas would be helpful. I can provide more code if necessary.

EDIT:

This is how the data is pulled from a database into the this.mileage variable

```
            await axios.get(API_BASE_URL+'/claims/travel/mileage').then(response => {
                this.mileage = response.data.data;
                this.calculateMileage(0.55);
                let totalModel = {};
                totalModel.name = 'mileage';
                totalModel.amount = (this.mileage.length > 0) ?  this.calculateAmount(this.mileage) : 0;
                this.total.push(totalModel);
            });
```

mileage contains the following fields:

```
create table mileages
(
id bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
claim int not null,
vehicle text not null,
mileageType int not null,
mileageDate date not null,
mileageTime time not null,
mileage double not null,
reason text not null,
origin text not null,
destination text not null,
created_at timestamp null,
updated_at timestamp null
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

EDIT 2:

I have added this watcher in place but it only fires at the initial load

```
    watch: {
        deep: true,
        mileage: {

            handler(){
                console.log("Fired");
                this.calculateMileage();
            }
        }
    }
```

I suspect I need to make it watch the object items specifically somehow but I am at a loss at the moment.

Comment: In your computed properties, you are updating some data values. Vue doesn't allow this and it might not work as you expect. Computed properties shouldn't mutate any reactive data.

Comment: Use watch hook to check if there is a change in data & do actions accordingly. As for total amount calculation need to see your code. It will help if you can create a fiddle..

Comment: @MakSr I figured a watch would be the course to go down but just dont understand how it watches variable arrays / objects. I have no clue on JS Fiddle setup so will try to provide a little more detail which may be enough for me to work it out. I am adding it under "Edit" section in the question.

Comment: Ok so using the watcher I have added above now works when I add items to the mileage object but not when updating. I guess this is because its not watching for changes within the object array but at objects instead. I have already added deep:true so I have no idea at this point.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. To watch a variable inside an object use watch function as this -> 'mileage.mileageItem':function(newValue){} & for object itself mileage function(newValue){}. And let me see your other problems. I will answer on a bit

Comment: I tried this too:         `watch: {

            'mileage.mileage'() {
                console.log("Fired");
                this.calculateMileage();
            }
        }`
Note that mileage is one of the items in the mileage object array